# Dataweave Mulesoft from array to object with reduce?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

In Mulesoft dataweave I have to change an array in an object. I tried it with reduce but for some reason it does not work.
Dataweave 2.0 and Anypoint platfrom version 4.4.0

```
{
    "option1": 0,
    "option2": 100,
    "options": [
        {
            "itemnr": "111111",
            "color": "red",
            "parts": 12,
            "year": 2022
        },
        {
            "itemnr": "222222",
            "color": "blue",
            "parts": 14,
            "year": 2022
        }
    ]
}
```

This must be the outcome:

```
{
    "Abs": {
        "El": {
            "Fields": {
                "itemnr": "111111",
                "date": "2022-08-02",
                "parts": 12,
                "color": "red"
            },
            "Fields": {
                "itemnr": "222222",
                "date": "2022-08-02",
                "parts": 14,
                "color": "blue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this but really strange things happening, code is displayed in reverse order.

```
{Abs :
    {El :
        {fields :
            (payload.options) map  {
                itemnr: $.itemnr,
                date: now() as Date,
                parts: $.parts,
                color: $.color
            } reduce ((item, accumulator) -> (item ++ {fields: accumulator}))
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the code `(item ++ {fields: accumulator})` . Changing it like below will give you your desired result.

```
{Abs :
    {El :
         
            (payload.options map  {
                itemnr: $.itemnr,
                date: now() as Date,
                parts: $.parts,
                color: $.color
            }) reduce ((item, accumulator = {}) -> accumulator ++ {Fields:item})
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{Abs :
    {El :
        
            {((payload.options) map  
               
                  (fields : 
                       {
                           itemnr: $.itemnr,
                           date: now() as Date,
                           parts: $.parts,
                           color: $.color
                       }
                  ))}
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
{
  "Abs": {
    "El": {
      "fields": {
        "itemnr": "111111",
        "date": "2022-08-02",
        "parts": 12,
        "color": "red"
      },
      "fields": {
        "itemnr": "222222",
        "date": "2022-08-02",
        "parts": 14,
        "color": "blue"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this solution also works and it is much easier as with the reduce. But I asked for a reduce, because I want to understand the reduce method.